# Namespace 'global.NodeJS' has no exported member 'Timeout'

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, openlayers

I'm running the following code in an angular component which integrate an open layer map :

```
enablePinpointMode(): void {
this.pinpointMode = true;
const pointerInteraction = new Pointer({
  handleDownEvent: (event: MapBrowserEvent<MouseEvent>) => {
    if (this.pinpointMode) {
      const coords = this.map!.getEventCoordinate(event.originalEvent);
      console.log('Pinpoint Coordinates:', coords);
      // Here, you can save the coordinates or use them as needed in your application
    }
    return true;
  }
});

this.map!.addInteraction(pointerInteraction);
```

}

This lead to an error :

```
Error: node_modules/ol/interaction/DblClickDragZoom.d.ts:103:33 - error TS2694: Namespace 'global.NodeJS' has no exported member 'Timeout'.

103     doubleTapTimeoutId_: NodeJS.Timeout | undefined;
                                   ~~~~~~~
```

I tried to delete my nodes module, and to npm install again. I also tried to npm update the type/node without success.

What's wrong ?

Comment: Perhaps because `doubleTapTimeoutId_`  has not been typed in the constructor?https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/src/ol/interaction/DblClickDragZoom.js